# Xamarin.Forms - ACR.UserDialogs - Alerts do not dismiss on touch anywhere

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have researched quite a bit but have yet to find and answer to my question, so I thought I'd ask here. I am currently using the latest version of ACR.UserDialogs (as of 2/12/2020) and I am unable to get an Alert to cancel when touching anywhere on the screen on an android device. I can only get the alert to dismiss by touching the dismiss button on the alert itself. Touch anywhere to cancel an Alert is available on the native Alert. Is there a way to achieve the same using the Alert from ACR.UserDialogs?

Here is the call to an alert:

```
UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Some Message", "Some Title", "Cancel");
```

Comment: Could you please edit question and post an MVCE ? Else, it will eventually get closed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I posted the one line of code that would call an alert using acr.userdialogs. The reason I did not before is that there really is only one line of code to call it and you have to be familiar with the package to be able to answer the question.

Comment: Never used it, but looking at their github, do you need to set an AutoCancel property or something like that. This is from their example view model         https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/95d79156fbce25d7db5b1b8ee2b19cf50a919d8b/src/Samples/Samples/ViewModels/StandardViewModel.cs#L269

Comment: I think it is by design and the library is not supported to customize the dialogs.